# Unity Vector Find an intersection with a circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

Hi I'm stoked for two weeks for this small problem
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Vector2 pC = pA+(pB-pA).normalized*r;
```